# Find out if a fb user is app admin in spring social/java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

Im developing a Facebook app with java and spring social. Is it possible to find out if a logged in user is admin of the current app? I have been looking through the api but cannot find anything. Or is there any other good way to do this with java.

Update: 
I did not find an specific api call in spring social to do this but it is possible to do the following which returns a json string with all the roles for the app.

```
facebook.restOperations().getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/roles?access_token=your app token", String.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Graph API with an HTTP GET to `/me/accounts` with that user's access token with `manage_pages` permission.  If you see the app listed there, then they're an admin or a developer.

Or you can use an FQL call. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/

`SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()` and see if the user is on that list.

**EDIT**

I just found a third way to check if a specific user is an admin of the Page, issue an HTTP GET request with the appropriate PAGE_ID, Page Access Token, and USER_ID to `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/admins/USER_ID`

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at the first option. Note that im here talking about an app so I don't have a page id.

Comment: Just try looking in the list of me/accounts.  Do you see your app listed there? If not, then you're not an admin.  If you do, then you can use any of the three ways above to get it done.

Comment: Ok, I still have not found out a way to do it in spring social but will do it as you described.

Comment: Can spring social call the graph??  If so, **any** of the three answers above can be gotten thru spring.